# I want to remove special characters from File name without affecting extension in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, c#-4.0

I have a file name let's say o example  - `Hello%@Im&an#Full-Stack+.Developer.pdf`

I want to replace all the special characters from the file name with underscore `_` and the result should be something like that.

`Hello__Im_an_Full_Stack_Developer.pdf`

Can anyone help me in making the regex for this task, my current regex is this `[^\.\w]`

Comment: If you want to change the dot before "Developer" to an underscore, you need to simply have `[^\w]`.  Handle the file extension specially (using the `Path` class).  By the way, you might want to point out what's wrong with the Regex you show.  We aren't that good at mind reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Path` to split file name

```
var fileName = "Hello%@Im&an#Full-Stack+.Developer.pdf"
var fileNameWoExt = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension();
var ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
fileNameWoExt = Regex.Replace(fileNameWoExt, @"[^\w]", "_");
var result = fileNameWoExt + ext;
// "Hello__Im_an_Full_Stack__Developer.pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```cs
var filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"(?!\.\w+$)[\W_]", "_");
// => Hello__Im_an_Full_Stack__Developer.pdf
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F!%5C.%5Cw%2B%24%29%5B%5CW_%5D&i=Hello%25%40Im%26an%23Full-Stack%2B.Developer.pdf&r=_). `(?!\.\w+$)[\W_]` matches any non-word or `_` char that is not a starting point of a `.` + one or more word chars at the end of string sequence.

Or, if you plan to replace sequences of special chars with a single `_`:

```cs
var filename = Regex.Replace(filename, @"(?:(?!\.\w+$)[\W_])+", "_");
// => Hello_Im_an_Full_Stack_Developer.pdf
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%28%3F!%5C.%5Cw%2B%24%29%5B%5CW_%5D%29%2B&i=Hello%25%40Im%26an%23Full-Stack%2B.Developer.pdf&r=_).

`(?:(?!\.\w+$)[\W_])+` matches any non-word or `_` chars, one or more occurrences, that does not start `.` + one or more word chars at the end of string sequence.

Answer (score 0):

I like idea of Genusatplay to separate filename from extension. But I do not like regex in code. I'd use Select method of Linq.

```
var letters = name.Select(x => IsLegalSymbol(x) ? x : '_');
name = string.Join("", letters);

private bool IsLegalSymbol(char c)
{
    // Modify it to be more or less strict
    return char.IsLetter(c);
}
```